# Open VLC live streaming from my Android app

Tags: android, vlc

Is it possible to open VLC live streaming link from my Android app using `Intent` or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work for you:

```
try
{
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //get an intent
    i.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon");
    //set the package name
    i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.linkofvideo.com"), "video/h264");
    //replace https://www.linkofvideo.com with the link or IP
    //replace video/h264 with the type of video
    startActivity(i);
    //start the activity
 }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            //app is NOT installed 
        }
```